# #define and #include order in C

Tags: c, gcc, include, c-preprocessor

I've following code which I compile with `gcc`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#define true 9
int main() { 
   printf("TRUE = %d\n",true);
   return 0;
}
```

And I get Error

```
test.c:3:0: warning: "true" redefined [enabled by default]
In file included from test.c:2:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/stdbool.h:34:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
```

But when I alter the code a bit

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define true 9
#include<stdbool.h>
int main() { 
   printf("TRUE = %d\n",true);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
TRUE = 1
```

**Question:**

I understand the reason for error in first case but In second case when I define `true` before I `#include<stdbool.h>`, why is it allowed to redefine `true`?

**Update:**

Here is [stdbool.h](https://gist.github.com/TheKojuEffect/6669422).

First few lines are

```
#ifndef _STDBOOL_H
#define _STDBOOL_H

#ifndef __cplusplus

#define bool    _Bool
#define true    1
#define false   0
```

which is nothing like in the Yu Hao 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18958248/1433665) .

Comment: I hope you're not seriously thinking about defining true

Comment: @Bathsheba I think the OP is doing a test, so he needs a different value than `1` to see which macro is working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although [*Yu Hao*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009479/yu-hao) gave a [possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18958248/694576) to the question, things indeed are different here.

This easily could be proved by looking into `stdbool.h` to realise that there is no `#ifdef ... #endif` "guard" around the definition of `true`.

Moreover gcc does simply surpress warnings that whould be given for issues in system headers<sup>*1</sup>.

Use the gcc's option `-isystem` to make the 1st example behave like the 2nd.

[From the gcc manual:](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html)

> The header files declaring interfaces to the operating system and runtime libraries often cannot be written in strictly conforming C. Therefore, GCC gives code found in system headers special treatment. All warnings, other than those generated by ‘#warning’ (see Diagnostics), are suppressed while GCC is processing a system header. Macros defined in a system header are immune to a few warnings wherever they are expanded. This immunity is granted on an ad-hoc basis, when we find that a warning generates lots of false positives because of code in macros defined in system headers.
>
> [...]
>
> The -isystem command line option adds its argument to the list of directories to search for headers, just like -I. Any headers found in that directory will be considered system headers.

---

<sup>*1: System headers are headers included in `<>` brackets.</sup>

Comment: Hmm `-isystem` does not seem to generate a warning for me in `gcc` but +1 this is a better explanation.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Sry, I mixed it up. Please see my  corrected my answer.

Comment: @alk No Error due to supressed warning because "GCC gives code found in system headers special treatment."?

Comment: @TheKojuEffect: Yes. But note that this "special treatment" does **not** refer to erros, but to warnings only.

Answer (score 9):

In the file `stdbool.h`, the code may look like this:

```
#ifdef true
#undef true
#define true 1
#endif
```

You should do the same when the macro may be defined before. Another similar trick is like this:

```
#ifndef MAGIC
#define MAGIC 42
#endif
```

**EDIT**

Turns out this is [gcc's feature](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html), see [@alk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18959236/1009479) for detail.

> All warnings, other than those generated by ‘#warning’, are suppressed while GCC is processing a system header. Macros defined in a system header are immune to a few warnings wherever they are expanded.

Comment: Well, it would have to be `#ifdef` then `#undef`, since in the second example the value from `stdbool.h` is printed rather than the manual `#define`.

Comment: "*... the code may look like ...*": but it doesn't. Please see my answer on to this question.

Answer (score -1):

Well, your warning already says it:

```
test.c:3:0: warning: "true" redefined [enabled by default]
```

GCC lets you redefine values unless you explicitly tell it not to. You can use -Werror for this.